# syntax error while finding the day of the date provided

Tags: python, date, time, calendar

I am solving a question on hackerrank to find the day of the date provided but I am getting a syntax error at daynumber(in the code).
How can I resolve it?

```
import sys,os,calendar

date,month,year=list(map(int(input().strip().split()))
dayNumber=calendar.weekday(year, month, date)
days=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
print(days[dayNumber])
```

Comment: Please edit your question to be a bit more legible. Use backticks for code, spaces between sentences etc... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You missed to close this tag ")"

```
date,month,year=list(map(int(input().strip().split())));
```

Comment: Thank for the help actually I did not put comma after integer and parenthesis before input() is useless.